# Looking for the code to generate jsessionid

Tags: jsessionid

I am looking for the default codebase for creating jsessionids.  It may vary from instance to instance, but I can't seem to find it on the net, just explanations of how to change/set it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

JSESSIONID cookie is created/sent when session is created. Session is created when your code calls request.getSession() or request.getSession(true) for the first time. If you just want get session, but not create it if it doesn't exists, use request.getSession(false) -- this will return you a session or null. In this case, new session is not created, and JSESSIONID cookie is not sent. (This also means that session isn't necessarily created on first request... you and your code is in control when the session is created)

Sessions are per-context:

```
SRV.7.3 Session Scope

HttpSession objects must be scoped at the application (or servlet context) level. The underlying mechanism, such as the cookie used to establish the session, can be the same for different contexts, but the object referenced, including the attributes in that object, must never be shared between contexts by the container.
```

Comment: Understood; but this is an explanation of what happens.  What I am looking for is how the cookie value is generated.  For example, here is an explanation for asp.net http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16822/The-Anatomy-of-Forms-Authentication

Comment: It looks like I found the code I was looking for in AbstractSessionIdManager.  This generates the string that becomes the cookie value for JSESSIONID.